# Mathematica: Exporting .gif files via Button

Tags: button, wolfram-mathematica, gif, animated-gif

I'm facing a problem with exporting files using `Button`. This piece of simple code just creates some data, namely a list of `Graphics` that I want to export as an animated .gif.

```
foo = Graphics /@
Table[{GrayLevel[RandomReal[]], Disk[{i, j}, 0.5]},
{k, 50}, {i, 10}, {j, 10}];
```

Now exporting `foo` using `Export["foo.gif", foo]` works as expected (even though it takes quite a while to do so).

However, when I create a `Button`, e.g. using `Button["Export!", Export["foo.gif", foo]]`, clicking the button causes Mathematica to freeze for some time. Afterwards, the evaluation seems to have stopped, but nothing was exported.

I want to use the button for exporting a similarly complex list of graphics in a `Manipulate` environment.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By default, button functions are evaluated on a preemptive link, which times out after 5 seconds
>
> Use Method->"Queued" to evaluate button functions on the main link, which never times out:

```
Button["Export!", Export["c:\\test.gif", foo], Method -> "Queued"]
```

[image]